# Ignoring actions with views in viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, swift, view, uiviewcontroller, viewdidload

I am doing doing the following operations in viewDidLoad:

```
view.window?.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
view.bringSubviewToFront(activityIndicator)
```

But the activityIndicator isn't showing up and I can still interact with the view. Whereas when I am doing the same thing in viewWillAppear, it is working correctly. What might be a reason?

Comment: In `viewDidLoad`, a view's window is normally `nil`. Use `viewIsAppearing`.